# Why doesn't the following work even though they both pointers point to the same address?

Tags: c

I am learning Structures and linked lists. When using a double structure pointer as head , I can't make it to direct to next element without using another structure pointer.

```
void pop(struct stack **headref,int element)
{
    struct stack *pop1=*headref;
    if(pop1==NULL)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    if(r==0)
    {
        printf("%d %d",*headref,pop1);
        //*headref=*headref->next     why doesnt this line work?
        *headref=pop1->next;
        free(pop1);
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the value of r (assuming is not a typo) ? Do this even compile ?

Comment: (a) major: there is no such this as `r` anywhere in this code until `if(r==0)`, and (b) minor: `element` seems completely pointless in that argument list. How about the *real* code, or better still, a [mcve]. Regarding `*headref=*headref->next`. It doesn't work for two reasons: 1. Operator precedence; that should be `*headref = (*headref)->next;` and 2. It isn't properly terminated with a `;`, so the line is invalid regardless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`->` has higher precedence than `*`.

`*headref->next` means `*(headref->next)`, while `pop1->next` is equivalent to `(*headref)->next`.

In other words, you don't need `pop1` if you add a pair of parentheses.